# Tips and Tricks for managing design View

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

Currently I am working on a project in which a combo box determines which panel is shown. This gets very messy since all the panels are on top of each other and it becomes very hard to determine what is what.

I was wondering if there is anything that can help me in Visual Studio 2013 to solve this.

Comment: Show a picture of your current project..

Comment: at the moment its simply a combo box with panels scattered around the form window so I can see everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Document Outline window`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46xf4h0w%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which provides an outline view of elements present on the form.

On the **View** menu in Visual Studio, click **Other Windows**, and then click **Document Outline**. The Document Outline window will open.

---

There is another link which explains **[How to: Layer Objects on Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh9zw57z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)**.

By layering you could manipulate their z-order of control at design view. There is option to change the Order of control either **Send To Back** or **Bring To Front**.

MSDN reference also explains how you could manipulate ordering programmatically.

Comment: +1 Document Outline View is a must when dealing with heavy drag and drop designs.